# How to add JUnit's JavaDoc to IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, javadoc

I successfully added Lucene's JavaDoc (a jar file) but failed with JUnit's JavaDoc since it's a directory so I need help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the path to the `javadoc` directory, like:

```
d:\dev\junit4.10\javadoc\
```

Comment: It works fine if you will try to view External JavaDoc (Shift+F1) for the classes that are actually available in this directory, for example `org.junit.Assert` will work, but `junit.framework.Assert` will not work as there is no documentation available for this class in the `javadoc` directory. So double check that you have appropriate classes imported.

Comment: Can I make a jar file like Lucene's javadoc from that javadoc directory ?

Comment: Yes, you can, but it's not necessary.